# bootstrap jquery popover size

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my application with bootstrap and fullcalender the size of the popover is not displaying correctly. Is it possible to adjust the size ?? I am using bootstrap 3. 
[image]

Code

```
$(window).load(function() { 
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        /* initialize the external events
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function() {

            // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
            // it doesn't need to have a start or end
            var eventObject = {
                title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
            };

            // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
            $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable({
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
            });

        });



        /* initialize the calendar
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
            eventRender: function (event, element) {
                element.popover({
                    title: "My Title",
                    placement:'auto',
                    html:true,
                    trigger : 'click',
                    animation : 'true',
                    content: event.msg
                });
                $('body').on('click', function (e) {
                    if (!element.is(e.target) && element.has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0)
                        element.popover('hide');
                });
              },

            events: [
                        {
                            title: 'All Day Event',
                            start: new Date(y, m, 1),
                            msg: 'I am OK',  
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'Long Event',
                            start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                            end: new Date(y, m, d-2),
                            msg: 'I am double OK',  
                        },
                        {
                            id: 999,
                            title: 'Repeating Event',
                            start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                            allDay: false
                        },
                        {
                            id: 999,
                            title: 'Repeating Event',
                            start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                            allDay: false
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'Meeting',
                            start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                            allDay: false
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'Lunch',
                            start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                            end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                            allDay: false
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'Birthday Party',
                            start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                            end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                            allDay: false
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'Click for Google',
                            start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                            end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                            url: 'http://google.com/'
                        }
                    ]       
        }); 

    });
```

JsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/7gwz5/

Answer (score 4):

Got solution for this

just added `{container:'body'}` to event pop over and it worked great

```
element.popover({
                title: "My Title",
                placement:'auto',
                html:true,
                trigger : 'click',
                animation : 'true',
                content: event.msg,
                container:'body'
            });
```

Updated jslint  http://jsfiddle.net/7gwz5/2/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know with `fullcalendar`, but classical Bootstrap popover structure looks like that :

```
<div class="popover">
    <h3 class="popover-title">Title</h3>
    <div class="popover-content">Content</div>
</div>
```

Then you just have to set size to `.popover` class, and it should work ; also verify that your javascript plugin doesn't alter the sizes, or change class (use Google Chrome's developer tools, for example).
If it still doesn't work, please post a fiddle with your code, we can easily debug it. ;)

Comment: Please see the updated fiddle with a `width` value for popover : http://jsfiddle.net/7gwz5/1/

Comment: :) css trick .thank you for replying  but the popup still showing beneath the full calender area  Is that possible to view outer ?

Comment: Which browser are you using ? With latest Chrome, the popup is showing over

Comment: On both chrome(29.0) and firefox(23.0) it is showing like that, Anyway thanks again for helping me:)

Comment: @JérémyDutheil how can i achieve this same functionality if i have the events in separate json file.. can you please show me a demo in fiddle..